# How to get style tag content with xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I must analyze the following html-content with xpath in python. The content I must get is the content of the style-tag.

```
<div class="chartBody">
    <div class="chartRow">
        <div class="chartLabel">Certificate</div>
            <div class="chartBar_g" style="width:300px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chartRow">
        <div class="chartLabel">Protocol Support</div>
            <div class="chartBar_a" style="width:210px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class which contains the style tag is different.
Can everybody tell me the xpath-string, to get all style-contents in a list?

Comment: Are you truly restricted to using the xpath, and what tools are you limited to? The task is relatively simple using Beautiful Soup or Selenium, but again we need to know more to pick the right tool

Answer (score 2):

`enter code here`1) Search for the Element that has the `style` attribute, e.g.:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class("chartBar_g")
```

2) get the style attribute:

```
element.get_attribute("style")
```

Here is how you can get "all" `div` elements that have a style attribute

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style]")
```

then you can just loop through the elements and apply what I described in step 2

Answer (score 0):

```
import html5lib

str = yourHtml
html_parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=html5lib.treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("lxml"), namespaceHTMLElements=False)
page = html_parser.parse(str, encoding="utf-8")
page.xpath("//div[@class = 'chartBar_g']//@style")
```

output is:
    ['width:30px']